# Simple Htaccess Regex

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file in the folder

```
http://localhost/modrewrite/test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^modrewrite/.*$
RewriteRule b.html [L]
```

All I want to do is whenever I go to index.php in that above folder, i want it redirected to b.html. I know this can be done by just using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.php b.html [L]
```

but I want to use RewriteCond and %{REQUEST_URI} to see how it actually works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I want to use RewriteCond and* `%{REQUEST_URI}`"

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
RewriteRule ^ b.html [L]
```

Though I will suggest that other rule is much cleaner i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ b.html [L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)